# Can we eat vishvaksena prasadam?

Tags: scripture, rituals, pancharatra, prasad, vishwaksena

In the Pancharatra Samhitas (Ishvara samhita and some others), it is explicitly stated that we should not eat food offered to Vishvaksena because it will trouble the lives of those who eat it.

I know that *priests* who take care of Vishvaksena sannidhi are allowed to eat...so what about prasadam offered to Vishvaksena at home? Can we eat it or not?

Scriptural references will be most useful.